# connect/ create relation two double linked lists in c

Tags: c, linked-list, connection, double

I want to create such a data structure that will allow to create a connection between two double linked lists. Here is the picture of relation.
[As you can see there is one double linked list at the top 1>2>3>9. Also each of these nodes are connected to another vertical double list. For example, 1>C>G, 2>A, 3>B, 9>E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNSey.png)
How can I establish such a connection between two different double lists?

Comment: The nodes in the top list have three pointers, the ones in the sublists are "normal" and jus have two pointers. That's really it.

Comment: @trincot sorry, but I am not sure if I understood you correctly. Do you mean that each node in top list has 3 pointers, namely previous,next and pointer to vertical list?

Comment: Just declare structs with the members you need. You can read off what kind of member each struct needs by looking at your picture. It is not hard. Write some code.

Comment: @Cheatah Is it correct? I am a beginner that is why I am not sure if I am doing correctly.                                                                                                             
  struct CountNode {
    int count;
    struct CountNode* next;
    struct CountNode* prev;
};

struct QueryNode{
    char query;
    struct CountNode* valuep;
    struct QueryNode* next;
    struct QueryNode* prev;
};

struct QueryTable{
    int value;
    struct QueryNode* queryp;
    struct QueryTable* next;
    struct QueryTable* prev;

};